# Is it possible to edit an existing JS file through React Native code?

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-ios

I am developing a React Native application, where I have to download a set of files and then make a few changes in the downloaded file based on the mobile phone's root directory. The path is unique for every mobile device so I have to change it only after the application is installed, which can not be pre-coded in the JS file.

Answer (score 2):

Your JS files are actually bundled up into one file in a React Native app. This is therefore not possible.

The typical approach in this type of scenario is that your code stores these *paths* either into an external file or into the app's persistent storage (perhaps ASyncStorage). Then whenever you need to, retrieve those *paths* at runtime from wherever you've stored it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Actually, I do not want to edit the files in a React Native application. But, I want to edit the files I download via my application. It could be a JS file, a HTML file etc.

Comment: @GauthamRajAyyapparaj Although your question was not about this, but this answered my question. Thanks!!